# XVWA (Xtremely Vulnerable Web Application) and XAMPP

Tags: google-chrome, xampp

I have downloaded XVWA from Github. I have downloaded the zip file on my Windows system. I have extracted all the files from the zip file in the htdocs folder of XAMPP [kept in Local disk (C:)]. I have started the XAMPP v3.2.2 - both MySQL & Apache (both running). I have opened chrome (incognito mode) and putting "localhost" in the URL. The page is showing "The site can't be reached-localhost refused to connect. Where am I going wrong? 
***Adding after doing some steps.*** 
After watching a video I have modified my URL as localhost:8080 and now two errors are being displayed. 
**Warning:**

```
mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'xvwa' in C:\xampp\htdocs\config.php on line 7  and another error is
```

**Fatal error**:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'xvwa' in C:\xampp\htdocs\config.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\config.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\header.php(18): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(34): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\config.php on line 8.
```

***Adding again after doing some steps***
Had a PHP file in htdocs folder and I renamed the file to config.in.php and then again modifying the URL as http://localhost:8080/setup/ I am getting this page
the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtOwI.png). Where am i doing the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Open "localhost/phpmyadmin"

Go to "Databases"

Create database "xvwa"